# How to execute three different formulas based on certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

How can I execute three different formulas based on certain criteria:
For example:

[image: See Attached Example]

There are three different formulas that I wish to execute based on which categorical condition the Numeric Value fall into.

Instead of manually checking it, is there a way (such as using the if else statement) for excel to automatically choose the correct formula based on the condition the numeric value fall into?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you share with us what formula(s), or VBA, you have already tried?

Answer (score 2):

`=IF(Condition A, Formula A, IF(Condition B, Formula B,IF(Condition C, Formula C)))`

In B7: `=IF(B7<=B3,B9-B$4,IF(B2>=B7>B3,B7+B$4,IF(B7>B2,B25*B$4)))` then drag down. I believe that this is the result you wanted. If not, state otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Expression

```
(B7-B$4>$B$3)+(B7-B$4>$B$2)+1
```

produces an index (`1`,`2` or `3`), according to the condition in question.
This index can be used to choose the function:

```
=CHOOSE((B7-B$4>$B$3)+(B7-B$4>$B$2)+1,"Func1","Func2","Func3")
```

Replace `"Func1","Func2","Func3"`with the actual expressions.

[image]